# iOS AWS S3/DynamoDB Design for Video Recording App with Cloud Storage

Tags: ios, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm creating an iOS app that allows users to:

1. Log into the app
2. Record videos
3. Upload the videos to the cloud
4. Watch their videos stored in the cloud

What is the best way to design the backend? Normally I would use Parse (which I've used previously), but given that they're shutting down, I need to find a new solution. Keep in mind that I've never done server side programming before.

I was thinking of using a configuration as follows:

**AWS DynamoDB**

- Usernames, passwords, emails, etc.
- Video meta data - titles, description, tags, etc.
- URL/pointers to video files on AWS S3

**AWS S3**

- Video files

**AWS Lambda**

- Processing of video files - compression, joining/splitting videos, etc.

This is my first time implementing a backend like this, so I was just wondering if this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I would Suggest You Can Add SQS In There It will help decouple.
SNS For Notification and SES For Emails.
AWS Elastic Transcode to maintain Uniformity (For Video Conversion if Required)
Also I would Suggest Using of AWS CDN So that the end users get Benefit out of it.

Using of AWS Glacier for storage of Retired User Who have Not Used Account Since Long Time (whatever Limit you set) and Then Deleting it Permanently (After Set Time is spent in glacier storage).